# Map Type Control False Value

Tags: google-maps, dictionary

Why is the Maptypecontrol still showing on my map in the homepage even though its value is false?   [www.driftcoffeehouse.com](http://www.driftcoffeehouse.com)

```
if (status == 'OK' && results.length > 0) {
var latlng = new  google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.b,results[0].geometry.location.c);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 13,
maptypecontrol: false,
center: results[0].geometry.location,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still there because you used `maptypecontrol` instead of `mapTypeControl`.

JavaScript is a case sensitive language: keywords, function names, variables, identifiers... everything is case sensitive so `maptypecontrol` is different from `mapTypeControl`. And because `mapTypeControl` is not there, default value `true` is used.